# Ruby hash of arrays issue

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

I am new to ruby and its nuances but I am running into this issue that I dont quite know how to fix or understand:

If I create the hash:

```
test = JSON.parse('[
    {"values":[
        ["header 1", "header 2", "header 3"],
        ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]]
    }]
')
```

Then I access test.values[0] I get:

```
[[["header 1", "header 2", "header 3"], ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]]]
```

As you can see it adds an extra layer onto the array. where what I would expect it to return would be:

```
[["header 1", "header 2", "header 3"], ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]]
```

Can anyone explain this to me or help mitigate this issue?

thanks!

Comment: you shouldn't be calling `.values` on an array (which is what `test` is)

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error for *undefined method*.

Comment: Thank you to the people who responded to this post. It definitely is that values is a method, and the unintended consequences from that was that it didn't go in and grab the key then get the contents but instead called the method values.

Comment: It absolutely doesn't when I run that code in Ruby 2.3.1. Maybe you have some library added on that's adding that method, but it's non-standard. Are you using [Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) or something else that extends Hash? If you are that would be `test[0].values` not what you put there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly certain that you aren't accessing the data in the right way as this:

```
test = JSON.parse('[
    {"values":[
        ["header 1", "header 2", "header 3"],
        ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]]
    }]
')

puts test[0]['values'].inspect
puts test[0]['values'][0].inspect
```

outputs:

`[["header 1", "header 2", "header 3"], ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]]
["header 1", "header 2", "header 3"]`

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON contains a key called **values**. In order to receive values from the hash try using it like this `test[0]['values']`. When using `test[0].values` you are actually calling `Hash#values` (instance method of Hash class) which returns all the values of every single key in your hash combined into the array.